# How do I configure the touchpad so that the cursor doesn't move when I click?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, sensors

Just installed 12.04 LTS and I experience some problems with my touchpad. Everytime I tap/double tap, the cursor is moving around (not static as should be). For example if I want to close a window, I click on "x" button from touchpad, the cursor is moving and not always hit the "x" button. Touchpad buttons left click, right click are working well, but tap not. Did u guys experience the same problem? Is there something related to sensitivity? How to fix it?

PS: on Ubuntu 11.10 didn't had this issue

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your touchpad still feels too much pressure when your finger is released.

If you are using synclient, you might try to increase the `FingerLow` value.

here is how I did with my computer:

```
$ synclient | grep FingerLow
    FingerLow      = 30
$ synclient FingerLow=35
```

Note that FingerLow cannot be higher than FingerHigh. So change this value as well if needed.

Comment: The SamK's answer works for me, it's just a driver configuration issue. To make the configuration permanent I created the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with [this content](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7165742/). The values should be configured experimentally.

Comment: Values that work well for me on a System76 Galago UltraPro are: FingerHigh=50, FingerLow=45.

Answer (score 6):

After digging through the available options to synclient it would seem that

```
Option "HorizHysteresis" "40"
Option "VertHysteresis" "40"
```

effectively prevents the pointer from "skipping" when I click. I also enabled two finger scrolling.

My /etc/X11/xorg.conf file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "FingerLow" "30"
    Option "FingerHigh" "40"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1"
    Option "TapAndDragGesture" "0"
    Option "HorizHysteresis" "40"
    Option "VertHysteresis" "40"
    Option "ClickPad" "1"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

This helped with my HP ENVY 17, took some tweaking of the numbers and it's pretty good now.