# Touchpad cursor jumps on click (not typing)

Tags: touchpad

I have setup my touchpad so that it doesn't move around when I am typing with the following config: https://github.com/fommil/unix/blob/master/Profiles/Sampo/.xsession.local

but it is incredibly infuriating that the cursor jumps (transports to another location, far away from where it was) sometimes when I am moving the cursor or - especially - when I click something. A double click triggers this with a high degree of repeatability.

This is definitely not an accidental "palm" detection, because even intentional random movements on the touchpad don't produce such a dramatic movement. When the cursor jumps, it tends to go to the middle bottom of the screen. i.e. this is not [what some other people call "jumping"](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-fix-cursor-jumping-in-ubuntu/).

I also have a touchscreen, but the problem continues even when I disable the touchscreen with xinput.

This is the xinput setup for my touchpad, any advice greatly appreciated as this is driving me crazy:

```
xinput --list-props 12
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (133):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (260): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (261):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (262):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (263):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (284):  1766, 5382, 1639, 4491
Synaptics Finger (285): 20, 50, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (286):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (287):   235
Synaptics Tap Durations (288):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (289):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (290):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (291):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (292):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (293): -111, -111
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (294): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (295):   1, 0
Synaptics Move Speed (296): 1.000000, 3.000000, 0.037362, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (297):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (298):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (299):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (300): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
Synaptics Click Action (301):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (302): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (303):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (304): 0
Synaptics Palm Detection (305): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (306):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (307): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (308):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (309): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Grab Event Device (310):  1
Synaptics Gestures (311):   0
Synaptics Capabilities (312):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (313): 60, 45
Synaptics Area (314):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (315):  3574, 0, 4125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (316): 26, 26
Device Product ID (252):    2, 7
Device Node (253):  "/dev/input/event7"
```

Comment: Have you tried something from these answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128023/how-do-i-configure-the-touchpad-so-that-the-cursor-doesnt-move-when-i-click

Comment: that is **not** the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: Might the pad be defective?

Comment: same problem here also.